# Set UIImageVIew frame according to Image's Frame contain By UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiimageview

I want to set the UIImage View Frame according to frame of Image which will show in UIImge View.I am using below code for that:-

```
[mainImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,mainImageView.image.frame.size.width,mainImageView.image.frame.size.height)];
```

But This Code Shown An Error.

Comment: Hi Rahul, Did you got the cropping an image idea, please share with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A UIImage doesn't have a `frame` property. Try `mainImageView.image.size.width`. (I haven't tested this.)

Comment: @Tommy Herbert i Want to do this beacuse in my app i have  taken a image From Photo LIbrary and CRopped a part of Image and saved a cropped Image. Problem is that when i cropped an Image Image is stretch. I want to make a frame of UIImageView constatnt before crop and after.so, can u give me an advise.thanks for your valuable Time

Comment: I think this is Summer Vacation of STackOverflow.No help Yet Come.

Comment: Firstly, you should un-accept my answer if it hasn't solved your problem (and if the site will let you). After that, have you tried UIView's sizeToFit method?

Comment: @Herbert You have answered my very First Question and it was correct Thats why i accept your Answer.

Comment: @Tommy Ok.can u tell me what will code for set the 
1.) origin of UIImage.
I am using: UIImage.size.origin.x = 45;
It show an error;

Comment: A UIImage isn't a kind of UIView: I don't think it has an origin. You can position it on the screen by putting it in a UIImageView, and set the origin of that.